# How to bind nested object within Form?

Tags: angular, bind

I bind data received from an API to a Form this way:

```
 // json data
 export class Recipe {
    _id: String;
    nome: String;
    tipo: Number;
    panetti: Number;
 }

 // ts (load data from API)
 this.form = this.fb.group({
    nome: [data.nome, [Validators.required]],
    tipo: [data.tipo, [Validators.required]],
    panetti: [data.panetti, [Validators.required]]
 });
 
 // component
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="nome">
 </mat-form-field>
```

but how can I do the same if the object become complex? Such as:

```
 // json data
 export class Recipe {
    _id: String;
    nome: String;
    tipo: Number;
    panetti: Number;
    ingredienti: {
        newField1: Number,
        newField2: Number,
        newArray: [
            {
                arrayField1: Number,
                arrayField2: Number
            }
        ];
    }
 }
```

how can I bind in this case newField1 and newArray/arrayField*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'ingredienti' you'll have another form group. Something like

```
 this.form = this.fb.group({
  nome: [data.nome, [Validators.required]],
  tipo: [data.tipo, [Validators.required]],
  panetti: [data.panetti, [Validators.required]],
  ingredienti: this.fb.group({
    newField: ['initialValue'],
    secondField: ['initialValue'],
  })
});
```

And if you have a dynamic array field, for 'newArray' you could use FormArray. Take a look here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray.

Edit for Markzz comment:
On your html form tag you're using [formGroup]="form".
Inside of it (where do you want to display the rest of fields), you're using 'formGroupName'. (ideally using with ng-container because it's not rendered to the dom).

Comment: and for the html part? should I insert a form within a form? :O not sure this is legit...

Comment: You do not insert another form. You're using a 'formGroupName' with the inner group name

Comment: Tried. It says "There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with path: 'ingredienti -> acqua'" when I deselect the input

Comment: Then you're setting your form in a wrong way. The above example should work without a problem.